# IllegalStateException when running logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

When I am running logstash it runned previously today when I am trying to run that it is throwing the error like this

---

```
"warning: ignoring JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
[ERROR] 2020-03-04 17:06:29.591 [main] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (RuntimeError)

        you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case there is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with `lock_jars` command

no such file to load -- /Users/******/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2 (LoadError)
```

Comment: If my answer is usefull, feel free to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Your java version doesn't compatible with this version of the logstash. You can change java version or you can use OpenJDK in the logstash. I suggest you use jdk 1.8. That will solve your problem.